# Can't start multiple drivers in multiple threads

Tags: qaf

Steps To Reproduce

1. Login to Baidu
2. Search something
3. Set thread-count = 5
   Expected behavior
   Each thread should initial one driver. For example, i have 3 cases, should start 3 drivers.

Actual behavior
All the thread use the same one driver (it means only start 1 driver).
For this, if the case has many steps, it seems not support multiple threads due to the only one drier.

[scenario image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/llrTp.png)

[testNG file image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OxpYS.png)

[test data image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BAUpB.png)

[java script image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KjjQn.png)

Answer (score 1):

I have configured as you mentioned, but it will only run one case and ignore others.
But if I set global.datadriven.parallel=false, it will run correctly.
[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: @user861594 can you help on this?

Answer (score 0):

This is possible duplicate of [how-to-run-test-cases-in-parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55201446/how-to-run-test-cases-in-parallel) and [qaf-weird-behavior-for-parallel-testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66792866/qaf-weird-behavior-for-parallel-testing/)

For data driven tests, set `global.datadriven.parallel=true` and set thread count in xml configuration file using `data-provider-thread-count`

Comment: But three drivers are started one by one, not at the same time. Do you know how to resolve it? It not supports multiple threads now.

Comment: try using `parallel=methods` in testNG configuration file